# jQuery append/appendTo/prepend/prependTo, second call removes first

Tags: jquery

Demonstrating difference between `append` and `appendTo` to my students yesterday and found this behaviour I do not understand. The first append fires and updates my page as expected, but when the second one fires it removes the first update. I would have expected a second copy appended, but it did not. I then tried with a `prepend` and an append and had the same behavior. It seems that the first statement runs (I stopped things in the debugger and looked) and then the second statement undoes the first one. Very simple code here:
HTML:

```
<div id="group-friends" class="group">
       <label>Your friends:</label>
       <input type="text" name="friends[]" value="Joe Schmoe" placeholder="Your friend's name">
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
 integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  var $group = $('#group-friends');

  var $copy = $group.find('input:last').clone();

  $group.append($copy);
  $copy.appendTo($group);
});
```

No matter what combination or order of append/appendTo/prepend/prependTo I do, only the second one is there at the end.

Is this me doing something odd or expected behaviour and if expected, why?

Comment: When you use `.append` or `.appendTo`, (prepend etc) it *moves* the content to the new location.  Frequently, we use these with new html so don't notice the move.  In this case you use it with a copy so the first isn't moved as it's copied, but the second call then moves that copy to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have cloned the element only once and instance of the same cloned element is being appended in second call.

If you expect the logic to work multiple time then you should re clone the element. something like this:

```
$group.append($copy);
$copy.clone().appendTo($group);
```